# PHP enforce passed in status is one of class constants

Tags: php

I am writing a wrapper class for updating the status of an API job in **php**. How can I check that the status passed into `update_status()` is one of the constants defined? Is there a better way to structure this?

```
class ApiJob {
    const QUEUED = "QUEUED";
    const RUNNING = "RUNNING";
    const FAILED = "FAILED";
    const COMPLETE = "COMPLETE";

    public static function update_status($id, $new_status) {
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
ApiJob::update_status(43842, ApiJob::RUNNING);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update_status function, check to see that $new_status is one of the 4 options and throw an exception if not.

```
switch ($new_status)
{
    case self::QUEUED:
    case self::RUNNING:
    case self::FAILED:
    case self::COMPLETE:
        // Set the status here. 
        break;

    default:
        throw new Exception("Status is not allowed.");
}
```